# Regarding Theorem 1.9, Conway, complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, riemann-sum, smooth-functions, stieltjes-integral

I have a doubt in equation (1.11) in Chapter 4, Section 1 of J.B Conway’s, functions of one complex variable.[image]

I know that the estimation of the integral in equation 1.10, comes from the previous theorem 1.4.

But what about the integral  $\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \gamma '(t) dt$? How is it approximated? By Riemann sums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f\gamma'$ is Riemann integrable, then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ whe $|P|<\delta$, we have$$\left|\overline{\sum}(f\gamma',P)-\underline{\sum}(f\gamma',P)\right|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$But if $P=\{t_0(=a),t_1,\ldots,t_n(=b)\}$, with $t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n$, and if, for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $\tau_k\in[t_{k-1},t_k]$, we have$$\sum_{k=1}^nf(\tau_k)\gamma'(\tau_k)(t_k-t_{k-1})\in\left[\underline{\sum}(f\gamma',P),\overline{\sum}(f\gamma',P)\right].\tag1$$but $\int_a^bf(t)\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt$ also belongs to the RHS of $(1)$. Since the length of that interval is smaller than $\varepsilon2$,$$\left|\int_a^bf(t)\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt-\sum_{k=1}^nf(\tau_k)\gamma'(\tau_k)(t_k-t_{k-1})\right|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Later in Definition 1.12, he defines the line-integral of $f$ along $\gamma$ as $\int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma '(t) dt$. Can you tell if yes then how the above inspires the definition of the line integral? If you want I can add this question in the main question.

Comment: I don't think that what's written above inspires somehow the definition of the line integral.

Comment: Then can you tell why do we learn the above before the definition of the line-integral.

Comment: It's so that that statement is ready to be used after we learn the definition of line integral.